# Wait until function from external library is executed in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-cognito

I'm new to TypeScript (and JavaScript) and I'm having some issues to wait until a function from an external library, namely `amazon-cognito-identity-js` is executed. I want to first authenticate an user and then get a token from that user. That's it. I read this [nice tutorial](https://sebhastian.com/javascript-wait-for-function-to-finish/) about Promises and there is also an [example on the official page of the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js), but seems like I'm missing something.

I created the following code:

```
import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserPool
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

var DEV_USER_POOL_DATA = {
  UserPoolId: 'userPool',
  ClientId: 'clientId'
};

var USER_POOL_DATA = DEV_USER_POOL_DATA;

function getJWT() {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => { 
    resolve();
  });
}

function login() {
  let userPool = new CognitoUserPool(USER_POOL_DATA);
  let authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
    Username: "myUser",
    Password: "myPass",
  });
  let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({ Username: "myUser", Pool: userPool });

  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function(result) {
      return result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
      console.log(err); 
    }
  });
}

getJWT().then(login);
console.log('Hello world');
```

However when I run the code I see

```
Hello world
<The actual token I will like to see first>
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Is this the line `getJWT().then(login())` giving that error ?

Comment: If so.... try this instead... `getJWT().then(() => login());`

Comment: Also... why don't you read about `async/await`... Very helpful and clean while using `Promises`...

Comment: Promise.then() expects a callback, you are passing the return value of login which in this case is undefined. Passing `login()` just executes it, you should do this instead, `getJWT().then(login)`

Comment: Thanks @YashVerma, I just realized that the code is running, but it is not waiting for the token. So, I have updated the question.